# apache rewrite through proxy remote

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, reverse-proxy

We are trying to write a reverse proxy rule to an external site.

```
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyRemote https://abc.company.com  http://proxy.company.com:80
    ProxyPass /_vti_bin/AccountList.asmx/ https://abc.comany.com/_vti_bin/AccountList.asmx/
    ProxyPassReverse /_vti_bin/AccountList.asmx/ https://abc.company.com/_vti_bin/AccountList.asmx/
```

As this is an internal application, I do not have direct connectivity to the external site from my apache http server. I am trying to go through the company proxy. But it's not working.

What's the ideal way to solve this?

Comment: Does your proxy server require authentication?

Comment: @HBruijn No, it does not

Comment: And testing from the command line on the apache server does work? `curl -v --proxy http://proxy.company.com:80 https://abc.comany.com/_vti_bin/AccountList.asmx/`

Comment: @HBruijn - yes it works and returns me a response with proper staus code